# Prevent split-brain/partitioning for RabbitMQ on OpenShift/Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, openshift

The cluster has 3 pods 3.7.5 RabbitMQ replica's in a StatefulSet. Using `rabbit_peer_discovery_k8s`, `cluster_formation.randomized_startup_delay_range` and `cluster_partition_handling = autoheal`

Sometimes when a pod restarts it can't connect to the existing cluster due to an `{badrpc,nodedown}` error. And then starts as a blank standalone node.

How can I prevent the standalone node?

Comment: Can you connect to your standalone pod and try to connect to the other nodes, and see if you have connectivity.  It's not clear whether it's a RabbitMQ issue or a Kunbernetes networking issue.

Comment: How do I check that, curl to the other node's dashboards works; so it's not connectivity?

Comment: It could be the port where your existing nodes are listening for consensus messages between your RabbitMQ nodes. Do all the nodes in your kubernetes cluster have the same firewall rules?

Comment: Yes and most of the times it works perfectly. It's just sometimes when the nodes restart it doesn't join the cluster.